# Nginx & Ruby on Rails - HTTP 301 moved permanently only on public IP addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, nginx

Full disclosure, I'm not a web developer... I'm a voice engineer who works with a particular product that uses nginx for a proxy, and rails for a website.

There's a tool I'm trying to use that makes an HTTP GET request to nginx, which is then passed to rails app, and it should return a 200 OK message. What I discovered was if the HTTP GET request comes from a public IP address, rails responds with a 301 moved permanently. If the HTTP GET request comes from a private IP address, rails responds with a 200 OK. The tool doesn't know what to do with a redirect, so it fails to perform the task it was written to do.

Why is rails responding differently to an HTTP GET request based solely on the private/public address? Is there a place where I can edit this behavior like a config file or something? Ruby on Rails is a black hole to me and was hoping I could get some help.

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Is it Rails that responds with 301 or is it nginx?

Comment: It's rails for sure. If you would like me to get any logs, or if there's some kind of debug on rails we can do I would be happy to perform and report back any info.